# What is Python's Fabric equivalent in other languages?

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what's the equivalent of Python's [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9/) in Python itself, other languages or third party tools?  I am still a bit fuzzy on what it is trying to accomplish and it's usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These tools are for performing common remote administration tasks usually as part of automated builds - a Ruby equivalent might be Capistrano, JSch in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It helps you to run commands on a lot of remote machines via SSH from your box. So you don't have to login on each one and copypaste the output of some machine back to your desktop.

Comment: Does that mean that I'm restricted to linux type OS?  I'm guessing that trying to trigger a Windows build with Fabric from my linux machine won't work.

Comment: There are SSH servers for Windows, but the command line environment they give you is probably not posix compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby community uses a tool called [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fabric example the first thing I thought about was mpiexec. Given right coding, I believe fabric can be used to run bot-nets or parallel processing clusters depending on your inclination.

Comment: Actually this is not true. Fabric is a deployment tool for "applications" it in fact the parallel parts of it where removed to simplify it's goal. No idea what you mean by bot-net really.